# How to get the lowest price in joined table ( laravel )

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Here's my code :

```
             return self::join('item_tags','tags.id', '=','item_tags.tags_id')
            ->join('items','items.id', '=','item_tags.items_id')
            ->join('item_images','item_tags.items_id','=','item_images.items_id')
            ->join('item_sellers','item_sellers.items_id','=','items.id')
            ->orderBy('item_sellers.price','asc')
            ->groupBy('item_sellers.items_id')
            ->paginate($paginate);
```

item table

[image: items]

item_sellers table
[image: here is the image of the data on my database]

Iam getting the 1466.00 price instead of 1400.00 price, can anyone help me with this problem? Thankyou

PS : I need to get the lowest price for every items_id.

Comment: you need to post other relevant table as well

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to `groupBy('item_sellers.items_id')`. You need to add `select` clause.

```
return self::join('item_tags','tags.id', '=','item_tags.tags_id')
        ->join('items','items.id', '=','item_tags.items_id')
        ->join('item_images','item_tags.items_id','=','item_images.items_id')
        ->join('item_sellers','item_sellers.items_id','=','items.id') 
        ->select(DB:raw('field1, field2, min(price) as price'))
        ->groupBy('item_sellers.items_id')
        ->paginate($paginate);
```

Or

```
return self::join('item_tags','tags.id', '=','item_tags.tags_id')
        ->join('items','items.id', '=','item_tags.items_id')
        ->join('item_images','item_tags.items_id','=','item_images.items_id')
        ->join('item_sellers','item_sellers.items_id','=','items.id') 
        ->groupBy('item_sellers.items_id')
        ->orderBy('item_sellers.price','asc')
        ->paginate($paginate);
```

Comment: I don't get it ,why do i need to select? i need to get the lowest price for every items_id.

Comment: you may try by reordering `orderBy` and  `groupBy` methode.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: `groupBy('item_sellers.items_id')->orderBy('item_sellers.price','asc')`

Answer (score 0):

```
return self::select("item_sellers.item_id",\DB::raw("min(item_sellers.price) as min_selll_price"))join('item_tags','tags.id', '=','item_tags.tags_id')
        ->join('items','items.id', '=','item_tags.items_id')
        ->join('item_images','item_tags.items_id','=','item_images.items_id')
        ->join('item_sellers','item_sellers.items_id','=','items.id')
        ->orderByRaw("min(item_sellers.price)",'ASC')
        ->groupBy('item_sellers.items_id')
        ->paginate($paginate);
```

Comment: Yes, i get the lowest price in every items_id, but the ID in the item_seller table, is different in what i am getting in this query, i supposed to get item seller id 28 because the id of the lowest price is 28, but i am getting the id 25

Comment: You have to specify the id you wants, instead * in select question, cause while using 8 have multiple id in result so you will always get last id column from result

Comment: Thanks! But how can i do it?

Comment: which id you wants ?

Comment: id in item_seller that have the lowest price on every items_id

Comment: hey? i don't know how get the id of the lowest price, can you help me again with this? i only getting the wrong id.

Comment: if i change the * to item_sellers.item_id, i get nothing in return.

Answer (score 0):

I think you nedd to try this :

```
return self::select("item_sellers.id","item.name","item_sellers.price")
        ->join('item_tags','tags.id', '=','item_tags.tags_id')
        ->join('items','items.id', '=','item_tags.items_id')
        ->join('item_images','item_tags.items_id','=','item_images.items_id')
        ->join('item_sellers','item_sellers.items_id','=','items.id')
        ->orderBy("item_sellers.price",'ASC')
        ->orderBy("item_sellers.id",'ASC')
        ->paginate($paginate);
```

Hope this help for you !

Comment: i'm not getting any return. i change the item_sellers.item_id to item_sellers.id nothing changed, still nothing in return.

Comment: there are an output, but still the same like earlier.

Comment: Im getting all the the item that i supposed not to get, i need only the item with the lowest price and their respective id.

Comment: im getting nothing in return again.